# Problem with @ViewScope and the @PostConstruct

Tags: java, jsf-2

My MBean is @ViewScope and the @PostConstruct is called when new instance is created and when made ajax request. this should happen?

Comment: The `@PostConstruct` should only be called after creation of new instance and not by an ajax call. Could you post some code of your bean and ajax call?

Comment: It sounds like something on your page is being re-rendered before the viewscope has been restored, so the container keeps creating new ones.  I know having a ui:include can cause this pretty easily, are you using that tag at all?

Comment: Paste your JSF page. It looks like view root is recreated. It happens for example when you try to use JSTL (e.g. c:if) in JSF code.

Comment: By MBean you mean JSF Managed Bean or JMX MBean?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is a bug in JSF that will be fixed only in the (upcoming) version 2.2 of mojarra.

See the detailed answer here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/8804317/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804317/postconstruct-method-is-called-even-if-the-managedbean-has-already-been-instant)

Answer (score 1):

`@ViewScope` beans have problems with some tags. for example:

- `<ui:include/>`
- `<ui:composition/>`
- `<c:forEach/>`

If your page has these tags, you may have a problem.

Comment: I have encountered this issue particularly with <c:forEach/>.