# primefaces command button action invoked after datatable load

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am facing a problem with primefaces command button and datatable. I have two buttons inside the datatable. when I click on the button everytime datatable loaded first and then button action invoked. I just want to avoid the datatable loading when button is clicked.

```
 <p:dataTable id="alphaTable" var="cs" binding="#{challengeSetBean.alphaChallengeSetTable}"
                        value="#{challengeSetBean.challengeSet}" styleClass="myTable"
                        style="list-style-type:none;width:600px;border:1px;" >

                <p:column id="col" style="width:20px;font-size:12px;padding-left:7px;padding-bottom:7px;padding-top:7px;">
                  ..................
                                      ................      
                </p:column>

                <p:column  style="width:28px;font-size:9px;padding-left:7px;padding-bottom:7px;padding-top:7px;">

                        <p:commandButton value="#{msg.updateAccount_reset}" action="#{challengeSetBean.editAnswer()}" immediate="true" rendered="#{!cs.editMode}" process="@this" update="col" >
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton value="#{msg.common_save}" action="#{challengeSetBean.saveAnswers()}" rendered="#{cs.editMode}" ajax="true" immediate="true" update="@form"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="#{msg.cancel}" action="#{challengeSetBean.cancelAnswer()}" rendered="#{cs.editMode}" ajax="true" immediate="true" update="@form"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="#{msg.common_delete}" action="#{challengeSetBean.deleteAnswer()}" rendered="#{!cs.editMode}"  immediate="true" update="@form"/>

            </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the bean in the view scope so that it would be instantiated only once on initial GET request and be reused on subsequent postbacks. Remove the `binding` attribute from the `<p:dataTable>` so that the view scoped bean won't be recreated due to chicken-egg JSF issue 1492. Now you can just load the `challengeSet` in the (post)constructor of the bean. It won't be invoked during subsequent postbacks.

#### See also:

- [Binding kills backing beans...what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038615/binding-kills-backing-beans-what-am-i-doing-wrong/13039809#13039809)
- [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable/4994833#4994833)
- [Recommended JSF 2.0 CRUD frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180400/recommended-jsf-2-0-crud-frameworks/3180885#3180885)